# In Emacs AutoComplete change order of sources in suggestion list

Tags: emacs, eclim

Is there a way to change the order of items in the suggestions list? I'm working with Eclim and it seems that the local buffer suggestions are the first, then snippets, and then the eclim ac source. I'd like to have the eclim source be first, followed by snippets, then anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ac-complete-eclim` to complete suggestions only from eclim source. You can bind that to a desired key for ease of use. Please refer to [Completion with Specific Source](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html#Completion_with_specific_source) section of the autocomplete mode manual for more information.

This is not an ideal solution. But, I use it for certain stuff. I would expect that candidates are shown in the order that sources are setup in `ac-sources` variable. But, that doesn't seem to be the case.